# Spring Data JPA JOIN query is too slow (matching each entry one by one)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I recently updated my project Spring Boot version to 2.5.1 which was 1.4.4-RELEASE and using Spring Data JPA. I noticed that my repository(extends JPARepository) methods that have JOINs take a long time to retrieve the results.

Let's say I have two tables named **A** and **B** that match the **A.x** and **B.y** columns. I am using a **native query** with @Query to retrieve the results and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.x = B.y
WHERE A.m = 'value' AND B.n = ('value')
```

Since I have set 'show-sql' to *true* I noticed that each match for B is separately fetched from the database and this takes a long time to complete if the data set is large. How can I stop this? Is there a way to overcome this issue? Maybe a configuration change?

I appreciate your concern. Thanks in advance!

Comment: JPA knows nothing about the SQL being used other than it must build what ever objects you specified (As?) and so has to build these entities based on your mappings. You must have an eagerly fetched relationship from A->B, forcing it to build a B instance for every A it builds. Remove it or mark it lazy if you don't need it. Alternatively you can use JPA provider specific behaviour to have it joined in (you'd have to change your SQL) or batch read in all Bs in a single query instead of individually for each A.

Comment: @Chris, Thank you very much for your response. It was marked EAGER. But marking it LAZY did not resolve the issue. As I dig deeper, I found that this issue is called [N+1 Query Problem](https://tech.asimio.net/2020/11/06/Preventing-N-plus-1-select-problem-using-Spring-Data-JPA-EntityGraph.html). I tried few approaches, but I still see additional query execution.

Comment: If it is fetching something marked lazy despite it being lazy - that is something you might want to track down. First guess is that something in your code is accessing it, forcing it to go to the db to be fetched - debugging would help. If you need that B data anyway in your app, then the N+1 query problem has many different solutions. Common ones involve joining the data (fetch join), or having your provider issue a bulk query (making it an 1+1 query problem). Fetch joins in JPQL is commonly used and easy to find examples, so you might want to use it instead of a native query.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for the explanation. As you explained, this issue can be addressed by the way we JOIN the tables/how we fetch the data. But as I realized, this is an Entity/Class level issue. 
In my case, A and B have a One-To-Many relationship, and B is defined as List<B> in class A with `@OneToMany` annotation.
As I observed when we fetch the main class(A), additional queries are executed to fetch associated classes(Bs). FetchType EAGER executes these additional queries with the main query while LAZY executes them when/if they are needed (please correct me if I'm wrong). cont.

Comment: This issue can be fixed with [JPA Entity Graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph).
_"Briefly put, the JPA provider loads all the graph in one select query and then avoids fetching association with more SELECT queries."_
[This article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs) explains how to use JPA Entity Graphs with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Yes, it is likely an issue at the class/mapping level. OneToMany are lazy by default, so shouldn't be fetched automatically unless you marked it eager to begin with, or something else is happening to trigger JPA to fetch that collection and read in the Bs. The SQL native query shown shouldn't force it, so it is something else.  Entity Graphs force loading, not joining, and are for JPQL/Criteria queries, not native ones. It is up to the provider on how they fetch the data requested in an Entity graph unless you resort to native hooks to tell it how (ie fetch/batch join annotations, hints etc).